# Unable to change the order of boot devices in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, installation, bootable-media

My laptop currently runs Windows 10 Enterprise 1511 (with all the updates).  Since Microsoft does not offer Update 1607 for the Enterprise version, I would like to install Windows 10 Pro.  However, there appears to be no option in the UEFI settings to change the order of the devices to boot from the CD-ROM first.

In the image below, only the blue text can be selected.  I tried pressing both "+" and "-" on the highlighted option to move it to the first position, but there was no effect.  Pressing enter takes me to a screen on which there is no blue (selectable) option.  The only thing I can do is to return to the screen below by pressing escape.

[image]

Any ideas on what I can do to force my laptop to boot from the CD-ROM drive?  Is it advisable to somehow ruin the installation on C drive from within Windows so that the computer then falls to the next available option?

Thanks in advance for your help.

**EDIT**

Laptop: MSI GP70 2QF Leopard Pro

All the drivers are up to date.  (I check regularly for driver updates.)

Comment: at boot press F11 or F12, those keys often open a boot menu were you can select which drive should be booted

Comment: Make and model of laptop would be nice.

Comment: @Moab I have added the information.  Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the F keys?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, I've tried the function keys, and also the escape and delete keys.  I remember that some of my older laptops required the delete or escape keys to be pressed before they would display the boot options.

Comment: look in the manual for help. this is often explained there